# Babel Obfuscator: Sample effective post build event for free version

Tags: .net, obfuscation

Does anyone have a sample post build event for Babel Obfuscator I can just copy and paste into my .net assembly release build configuration?

The documentation for Babel is 54 pages long, and unfortunately doesn't come with any real world samples on how to use it with Visual Studio integration.

Failing that , is there a free obfuscator out there that integrates well with VS 2008 post build, so that it will obfuscate the release DLL during each new build. I was using Eazfuscator which broke since they released version 2.8.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A post build event example is at pag 42 of the babel user manual:

```
babel.exe "$(OutDir)$(TargetFileName)" -v1 --keyfile "$(ProjectDir)StrongName.snk" --rules "$(ProjectDir)babelRules.xml"
```